# How to add/change Contacts Group notes

Tags: android, contacts

How can add a note to a group.

I try it

```
ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(Groups.NOTES, note);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I get my answer.

```
public static boolean setGroupNote(String groupId, String note)
    {
        try
        {
            if (groupId == null || note == null)
                return false;

            String where = Groups._ID + " = ?";
            String[] args = {groupId};
            ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(Groups.NOTES, note);
            int u = getContentResolver.update(Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, where, args);
            if(u != 0)
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return false;
    }
```